# Property change notification in AngularJS Directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a page with a large number of text boxes in an Excel-like layout. Each column represents a single object, and the cells in that column contain the object's properties. When a value in a cell changes (triggered when cell loses focus), I need to know the object and property that changed so that I can copy the values to the same property in other selected objects.

I have this working but it's a naive approach and I think it would be better to encapsulate this in a directive. The problem is that the directive I was able to write is as verbose as my first solution and doesn't seem to be an improvement.

The [first version](http://plnkr.co/edit/nO3NEnbS593YuQfK1kOL) simply passes the object and property name to a change handler function.

```
<td>
    <input ng-model="person.firstName" 
           ng-change="personChanged(person, 'firstName')" 
           ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" />
</td>

$scope.personChanged = function(person, property) {
  alert(person.personId + ' : ' + property);
}
```

The [second version](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZJjf5d3EKN3KPipFTq7g) uses a directive.

```
<td>
    <input ng-model="person.firstName" 
           name-changed person="person" property="'firstName'" />
</td>

myApp.directive('nameChanged', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      person: '=',
      property: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      element.bind('change', function(e){
        alert(scope.person.personId + ' : ' + scope.property);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

In both solutions, I am declaring the object and property name in attributes, which seems redundant because I have already provided both via ngModel. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `ngModel="person.firstname"`, angular will listen any changes on firstname attribute and it will only keep the value of firstname in you ngModel (check documentation on ngModel and ngModelController). That means you have to pass other information in your directive scope (eg person.id, property)

You should avoid two way binding where you can. Use '&' and '@' when you bind attributes to your directive scope.

Optimized version of your directive:

```
myApp.directive('nameChanged', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      person: '&',
      property: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel){
      element.bind('change', function(e){

        alert(scope.person().personId  + ' : ' + scope.property + ', value is : ' + ngModel.$modelValue)

      // dispatch your change to upper scopes
      scope.$emit('nameChanged', {personId : scope.person().personId, property: scope.property, value : ngModel.$modelValue});

      });
    }
  };
});
```

then in your controller handle this event :

```
myApp.controller('peopleController', function($scope) {
  $scope.people = [new Person(1, 'Homer', 'Simpson'), new Person(2, 'Ned', 'Flanders'), new Person(3, 'Otto', 'Mann')];


  $scope.$on('nameChanged', function(event, change){
    // changed detected inside one of ours dirctives
    console.log('changed detected from controller', change)     
    // do what you want with he new value : 'change.value'

  })

});
```

Note that event names should be in .constant module. It is better for maintainability.

[Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/vNTQJo9GoFV60I9I9rpl?p=preview)

You can achieve what you want both ways (with ng-change and an fn in your scope) or with a isolate scope directive. Personally I like doing it in directives to isolate responsability but it depends on you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's an improvement. I like the idea of encapsulating the functionality in a directive but I have the requirement that the changed property needs to propagate to other selected objects and the directive won't and shouldn't have any knowledge of those. I guess where I'm hung up is that Angular knows which object and property changed, but I have to tell it so that it can tell me.

Comment: I don't understand when you say 'the changed property needs to propagate to other selected objects'. Can you explain me or do another plunker? thanks

Comment: If the user has this feature enabled, changing "Homer" to "Marge" would change all people's first names to "Marge". The real-world scenario is that a user is entering a 20-year forecast and the amount is level over the period, so I need to give them an easy way to enter the same value for every year.

Comment: Yes we can, I'll edit my response and check my new plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/vNTQJo9GoFV60I9I9rpl?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. "All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection" :-). I ended up using my first approach.

Comment: Good choice ;). No need to complicate things