# AngularJS Async isolated directive is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to send an object returning from the DB to a child directive. When I am sending any kind of data in sync mode it works. However when I am doing the same thing but fetching the data from remote server - async method, the directive is getting fired **before** the results are coming.

This is the controller which fetched the data from the server:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/root/cardboards/employees/:_employee", {
        templateUrl: "screens/root/cardboards/employees-detail/employees-detail.html"
    });
    // $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

app.controller("employees-detail", ($rootScope, $scope, $location, $routeParams, Http, Cast) => {
    Http.GET({
        resource: `employees/${$scope._employee}`
    }, (err, response) => {
        if (err) return Cast.error(err);
        $scope.employee = response.data; // employee's object
        $scope.$apply();
    });
});
```

This is the directive element in HTML:

```
<edit-employee employee="employee"></edit-employee>
```

And this is the `edit-employee` directive js file:

```
app.directive("editEmployee", ($rootScope, Http, Cast) => {
    return {
        templateUrl: "/screens/root/cardboards/employees-detail/components/edit-employee/edit-employee.html",
        scope: {
            employee: "="
        },
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log($scope.employee); // undefined
        }
    }
});
```

I thought that when I am using the `=` operator it means that it's now two way binding and the directive will watch for changes and then having the functionality based on the data that will come after the request to the server.

However it doesn't work like that.

How should it work and what should I do, the standard way, to make thing working?

Comment: hope this would help you and keep as a reference 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33302769/property-change-notification-in-angularjs-directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `<edit-employee` being rendered it will try to get the `employee`to do a `console.log` on this line

```
link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
  console.log($scope.employee); // undefined
}
```

But unfortunately, at that time, the `employee` is still undefined since it waiting for the response from the server.
To understand more clearly about this you can initiate a `$watch` to watch the `employee` inside `edit-employee` directive, and whenever the `HTTP` is finished it will update the employee to newest value.

> How should it work and what should I do, the standard way, to make thing working?

It really depends, I meet that problem once and I used an ng-if on `<edit-employee ng-if='employee'` which mean the `edit-employee` directive will be rendered after the `employee` is initial `(!= undefine)`.

Another way is you watch the `employee` inside `edit-employee` directive and check if `employee` has value then continue the business logic

Comment: ...and 3rd way is using `resolve` section of `$routeProvider.when()` to declare data you need to load before navigating to template given